# Can I create a webpage to control another webpage in real time?

Tags: php, javascript, controls, html

My idea is to create three webpages. One serves as a display page, the other two serve as remotes that change the images in the display page. I wanna all the changes happen in real time in the display page. Is this achievable in HTML webpage? If so, what language or languages are needed? Can JavaScript alone achieve it?

Comment: i can imagine a how with ajax, but a why is more elusive.

Comment: you might need something like PHP (as you have tagged) for the javascript to be able to write the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at http://xsockets.net, if you are running on .net there is a set of samples included in the Nuget-Package that can help you out.   You can also use just a JavaScript API of XSockets.NET and a Cloud Hosted Service called http://live.xsockets.net

Comment: Also have a look at http://xfiddle.net , a good start to see how the JsApi works.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to do it in **real-time** would be using HTML5 Websockets. You would need a [NodeJS server](http://nodejs.org/) to handle the websocket connections. I would suggest using the package [SocketIO](http://socket.io/). Look out for chatroom examples or multiplayer game tutorials.

Your display page would opena websocket connection and a room. Also your 2 "remote" pages would join the room and the you would be able to exchange data from one page to another and executre javascript functions.